# Capturing video with opencv

Tags: c#, opencv

I'm trying to do

```
VideoCapture cap (../video.avi);
```

Getting an error: Couldn't read movie file .../video.avi

i'm using Opencv 2.3.1

Any suggestions? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to save a video stream (e.g. webcam) to disk, or are you trying to read from a video file?

In the first case, you capture from your default device with
         `VideoCapture cap (0);`

Then you have to use the VideoWriter class to save it to disk.

If you want to read from a file, then you are probably not using the right path.

Comment: If i'm trying to show video from my cam VideoCapture cap (0); everything ok, but if i'm trying to show video from my video-file, i'm getting an error

Comment: I need to do the same like Mat img = imread (".../img.jpg", 0), but with video

Comment: You are probably not using the proper path pointing to the file. If you are using Visual Studio look for the path where your program is debugged from, which is not necessarily the same path as the folder where it's generated.

Comment: it's impossible cause i copy the proper path from the terminal and i'm using QT Creator

Comment: i'm sorry, the problem was about using not english letters in the path